# CLANG bug in constexpr initializer

Tags: c++, string, clang, constexpr

I'm evaluating using a compile time value for the SSO maximum size to select an optimal container based on that size as well as how much heap is allocated when the size is exceeded.

Works fine except on CLANG where initializing a string with a standard, two argument ctor, fails.

```
constexpr auto MAX_SSO = []() {std::string s; return s.capacity();}();
constexpr auto MAX_SSO_PLUS1 = []() {std::string s(MAX_SSO+1,0); return s.capacity(); }();   // This line fails with CLANG
```

Here's a full example in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sbTdncrr8)

Changing the failed line to this also fails:

```
constexpr auto MAX_SSO_PLUS1 = []() {std::string s(1,0); return s.capacity();}();
```

But this works:

```
constexpr auto MAX_SSO_PLUS1 = []() {std::string s{"\0"}; return s.capacity();}();
```

Is this a CLANG bug?

Full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto MAX_SSO = []() {std::string s; return 
s.capacity();}();
constexpr auto MAX_SSO_PLUS1 = []() {std::string s(MAX_SSO+1,0); 
return s.capacity();}();

int main()
{
    std::cout << MAX_SSO << '\n';
    std::cout << MAX_SSO_PLUS1 << '\n';
}
```

GCC and MSVC no errors. CLANG error: constexpr variable 'MAX_SSO_PLUS1' must be initialized by a constant expression

Workaround: This works on CLANG as well as GCC and MSVC

```
constexpr auto MAX_SSO_PLUS1 = []() {std::string s; s.resize(MAX_SSO+1); return s.capacity();}();
```

Comment: What error is raised for users that do not go to outer links?

Comment: @273K Just added it: Complains not a const expr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Clang issue. If you had posted the full error message:

```
...
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.0.0/../../../../include/c++/14.0.0/bits/basic_string.h:662:9: note: undefined function '_M_construct' cannot be used in a constant expression
  662 |       { _M_construct(__n, __c); }
...
```

You would see

```
undefined function '_M_construct' cannot be used in a constant expression
```

and would notice that Clang uses the GNU standard C++ library:

```
.../gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.0.0/../../../../include/c++/14.0.0/bits/basic_string.h
```

Switch Clang to using the LLVM standard C++ library and it will compile:

```
-std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++
Compiler returned: 0
```

Why Clang does not work well with the GNU standard C++ library and why `_M_construct` is undefined for Clang is another topic.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize compiler explorer used GNU lib and not the LLVM. I mostly use MSVC and was checking it for portability. Looks like the workaround give me what I need. Was afraid I might be doing something marginal.

Comment: It can be also a configuration issue. Clang 15 still uses `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10` with `-std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++` if GCC10 is highest available. It maybe misconfiguration or somekind of software gore. Errors in verbose mode are diffrent, in non-verbose they are same as OPs. result is same.